# Error: ArrayList is already defined in this compilation unit

Tags: arraylist

The following code produces this compling error:

ArrayList is already defined in this compilation unit

```
import java.util.*;

public class FirstApp{

public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(scan.hasNextInt()){
   list.add(scan.nextInt());
}
Integer[] nums = new  Integer[list.size()];
nums = list.toArray(nums);
for(int i = 0;i < nums.length; i++){
System.out.println(nums[i]);
}
}
}
```

Comment: I dont see anything that would lead to compile time error.

Answer (score 3):

This code compiles correctly. Such an error may occur if you, for example, name your class  "ArrayList" and at the same time import ArrayList.